# sketch graph of derivative function from original function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

let us consider following  question  given on  image

[image]

because slope  is  equal to  rise over run, then we can calculate  slope at point  $x=-3$ by takeing following points

$(-3,0),(-1,2) so we have following form

$(2-0)/(-1-(-3))=2/2=1 $

is  part one correct?  and sketching of graph of derivatives will be simple plotting of values right?is there  more simple approach to do same? can i  estimate function itself?maybe i can guess that it is sinusoidal or some polynomial function and then  by inserting points  estimate its coefficients? thanks in advance

Comment: please consider converting the question (image) to text, that will make the question more readable and search-friendly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph the function $f$ seems an odd function, so its derivative $f'$ is even. This means that:
$$
f'(-3)=f'(3) \qquad f'(-2)=f'(2) \qquad f'(-1)=f'(1)=0
$$

we can also see that $f'(x)<0$ for $-1<x<1$ and it has a minimum for $x=0$ and it seems positive for the values $x<-1$ and $x>1$ ( but the graph is limited so we can not be sure about this).

From all this we can assume that (in the simpler case) the derivative has the form $f'(x)=k(x^2-1)$ for $k>0$ and the function has the form $f(x)=\frac{k}{3}x(x^3-3)$

Comment: so slope  $f'(-3)=0$ ?

Comment: No. From the graph we cannot find the exact value of the slope at $x=-3$. We can only see that it is positive: $f'(-3)=8k=f'(3)$, but the value of $k$ cannot be deduced by the graph without some other information.

Comment: but my friend from the graph we know that  $f(-3)=0$  how can we  know that derivative of function at point $x=-3$ is positive?

Comment: Yes, $f(-3)=f(3)=0$ but for the derivative we can only see, from the graph, that the slope of the tangent line at this point is positive, i.e. the derivative is positive.